# Degenerate typeclass instance declaration using constant value

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've reduced everything down to the essentials, so bear with me if the example code below is contrived. Let's say we have:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a

data Type a = Type a

instance (Foo a) => Foo (Type a) where
    foo = Type foo
```

Now, suppose I want to make `Type a` an instance of, say, `Show`  whenever `a` is an instance of both `Foo` and `Show` (`Show` was chosen to avoid defining another typeclass). So how do we want `Type a` to be an instance of `Show`? Well, unless we're crazy, we'd of course want it to be something like

```
instance (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a) where
    show (Type x) = show x
```

or maybe

```
instance (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a) where
    show (Type x) = "Blabla " ++ (show x)
```

That's all great and works fine. For some inexplicable reason, we'd like `show` to output whatever `foo :: a` looks/shows like! In our contrived setting I cannot imagine why we'd want that, but let's say we do. Shouldn't

```
instance (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a) where
    show _ = show foo
```

do the trick?

Alas, GHC says

> Ambiguous type variable 'a' in the
>   constraints: 'Foo a' [...] 'Show a'

Maybe GHC can't figure out which `foo` I'm talking about. Do I mean `foo :: Type a` or `foo :: a`? Changing the previous snippet to

```
instance (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a) where
    show _ = show (foo :: a)
```

gives me

> Could not deduce (Foo a1) from the
>   context ()
>         arising from a use of 'foo' at [...]
>       Possible fix:
>         add (Foo a1) to the context of an expression type signature
>       In the first argument of 'show', namely '(foo :: a)'
>       In the expression: show (foo :: a)

At this point I'm starting to think I've misunderstood something basic. Yet, I have the strange feeling that similar constructions have worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that type variables aren't scoped to definitions. That is, in

```
instance (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a) where
    show _ = show (foo :: a)
```

`a` in the second line is different from `a` in the first line, which is why it's shown as `a1` in the error message. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables. If this is the problem, this should work (I don't have GHC on this machine):

```
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf a b = a

instance (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a) where
    show (Type x) = show (foo `asTypeOf` x)
```

Comment: Good answer except for a minor typo which leads to non-termination: the last line should be `show (Type x) = show (foo \`asTypeOf\` x)`. You can also use `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` along with `show _ = show (foo :: a)`

Comment: Great! Thanks, this really clarified things. Thanks also to pelotom for pointing out the GHC extension.

Comment: The reason why I didn't mention the extension is that it requires that `forall` be written explicitly: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables, but I wasn't sure where it should go: `instance forall a. (Foo a, Show a) => Show (Type a)`? Somewhere else? Unnecessary for instances?

Comment: Alexey: I didn't need `forall` at least. In my example, I turned on the GHC extension and implemented `show` as `show _ = show (foo :: a)`. It's working perfectly. It's nice to know about your `asTypeOf` approach too.

Comment: "I didn't need `forall` at least." Good to know!